# How to make a number triangle

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a triangle that appears like

`1
12
123
1234
12345`

This code causes it to just print 1 over and over

```
def line(n):
    print('1' *n)

def triangle(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        line(i)
```

Comment: That's what the `*` operator is supposed to do on strings. `'1' * n` will give you a string containing `n` 1's. Your `line` function should have loop in it to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about (assuming Python 3):

```
def line(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(i+1, end='')
    print()
```

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, why not?  The question doesn't seem strange to me!

Answer (score 0):

You start with an empty string, increment it, and print it through the range.

```
def line(n):
    triangle = ''
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        triangle = triangle + (str(i))
        print(triangle)
        i+=1
```

This renders:

```
>>> line(5)
    1
    12
    123
    1234
    12345
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually came across same issue @ College :)

Here is my solution :) :

```
for n in range (1, n):
x = n
for x in range(0,x):
    print(x+1, end='')
print()
```

Produces exactly what you asked for using nested FOR loop:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```